# Show that $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Consider the statistical model where $Y_i \sim Bin(n_i, p_i)$ and define $X_i = \sqrt{n_i}\arcsin\bigg(2\dfrac{Y_i}{n_i} -1\bigg).$

**Question:** How do I show that $X_i|\mu_i \stackrel{ind}{\sim} N(\mu_i,1)$?

I think that $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$ if we have that $P(X_i\leq x) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\bigg(-\frac{(x - \mu_i)^2}{2\sigma^2}\bigg)dx$. But I don't really know how this will help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot show this because it's wrong… $Y_i$ is a discrete r.v. hence is $X_i$. But a normal distribution is continuous. So $X_i$ cannot be normal.

Comment: @Gono my book says you can.. I understand your objection, that's what I don't understand myself. In my book this transformation of $Y_i$ is called a variance stability transformation.

Comment: Maybe is $X_i \to X \sim N(\mu,1)$?

Comment: @Gono does this make any difference?

Comment: Wat does $X_i|{\mu} $ mean?

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question again, in light of the comments.  What is $\mu_i$?  It seems like you are asking a limit distribution question, but the details are so murky it is hard for us to understand what you are actually asking.

Comment: @kimchilover I would if I only know how! This is exactly how the question is posed in my book.